# Cannot downgrade from MySQL 8.0.12 to earlier version

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench

I've been searching around and haven't been able to find out how to downgrade my MySQL version. I've tried `brew info MySQL` then `brew switch MySQL 5.7.21` but it says it's not in the cellar.

I followed a guide running `brew install mysql@5.7` but when I check the -v it says its an unknown command.

let me know if I missed any details. this is my first time reaching out.

Comment: `brew services stop mysql`
`brew uninstall mysql`
`brew install mysql@5.7`
`brew link mysql@5.7 --force`
`brew services start mysql@5.7`

Comment: Don't forget to backup and export databases.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help!

Comment: this saved me so much time !

Answer (score 2):

**Using APT Repositories**

Step 1: Reconfigure MySQL and choose the older version:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config
```

Step 2: Run apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3: Remove the current version:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-community-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core -y

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Step 4: Install the older version (autoselected since you have reconfigured):

```
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

Comment: It looks like this answer was taken from [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788395809/1/ch01lvl1sec18/downgrading-from-mysql-8-0).

Comment: Of course not ........ And StackOverflow is the community where we are here to help each other not to get famous. So instead of focusing on copy-paste thanks every solution provider.

Comment: It's clearly copied from there, just give credit in your answer then it's not an issue, no need to get defensive. But don't claim it's your original answer if it's clearly copied.